# getting JSON data from PHP to iOS

Tags: php, ios, json

I'am developing an iPhone application to display data from php. Data are obtained from a Mysql database then encoded to JSON format in php file:

```
include_once 'connectionIncl.php';

if(function_exists($_GET['method'])){
    $_GET['method']();

}
function getSQLIntoJSONFormat()
{
    $arr;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pecivo");
    while($pecivo = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $arr[] = $pecivo['typ'];
    }
    $arr= json_encode($arr);
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.$arr.')';
}

// --- http://127.0.0.1:8887/TeplyRohlik/pecivo.php?method=getSQLIntoJSONFormat&jsoncallback=?
```

when i run this from browser, it returns correct data :

```
(["sejra","knir","baba","vousy","sporitelna25"])
```

Also, on iOS a have this code:

```
NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.10:8887/TeplyRohlik/pecivo.php?method=getSQLIntoJSONFormat&jsoncallback=?"];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError * error;
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

And result is .... (`null`).
I have no idea how to get this working...

Comment: have you tried if the URL is reachable from your device? Go to your phone-browser and type the url above to see if it's answering correctly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Why don't you look at the NSError object to find out more info? o,0

Comment: it will probably help to log the data (the http response) and the error from the json parser

Comment: What is the value of 'error'?

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that your container is not a dictionary.  It is an array!!

Comment: @mojomajor yeah i have and it worked just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your PHP method is spitting out [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). What you probably want to do is change that to:

```
function getSQLIntoJSONFormat()
{
    $arr;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pecivo");
    while($pecivo = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $arr[] = $pecivo['typ'];
    }
    $arr= json_encode($arr);
    echo $arr;
}
```

You are seeing the output be wrapped in parentheses as it's expecting a GET parameter in the request called `jsoncallback` which would make the output look something like this:

```
javascriptFunction(["a","b","b"])
```

That's not what you want on your iOS device. You want just the raw JSON string of the array, no wrapping in a callback function call.